# How do I change the output of `date` back to 24-hour format?

Tags: upgrade, date, locale, glibc

Apparently a recent change (in Glibc 2.29?) causes the `date` command to start printing times in 12-hour format:

```
$ date
Fri 23 Aug 2019 07:34:13 PM PDT
```

This is for my default locale

```
$ cat /etc/locale.conf 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

How can I configure my system to go back to displaying dates in 24-hour format?

Comment: What is LC_TIME set to, if anything? (Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation)

Comment: Same as LANG ...

Comment: See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24046 for the origin of the change.

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by jamespharvey20 on IRC, I just changed `LC_TIME` to another locale. I set it in `/etc/locale.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB
```

I also exported this value of `LC_TIME` in my shell profile, to avoid having to restart (I couldn't figure out how to get Systemd to reread the `locale.conf`). This seems a bit hacky but I think it's the best we came up with. Also, it preserves the new "DD MMM" format which I prefer to the old "MMM DD".

Comment: That also has the benefit of converting `strftime("%c / %X")` (like in `date +%c/%X`) to 24-hour format. You would have had 12-hour format in US locales even in older versions of glibc. Alternatively, you can use `LC_TIME=C` which would be more future-proof as the format is specified by POSIX and unlikely to change (and happens to be in English)

Comment: `cat: /etc/locale.conf: No such file or directory`